# React Laravel: Can't get the form to display once logged in

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I'm building a React Laravel hotel reviews app. I've been following this tutorial (https://kaloraat.com/articles/laravel-react-crud-tutorial), plus its github repo (https://github.com/kaloraat/laravel-react-crud). However, once you are logged in, the Review Form is supposed to show up, but it never showed up. I think that there is an error that is preventing `App.js` from showing up.

Here is my website where I hosted on heroku using postgres database: http://immense-beach-76879.herokuapp.com/ and my github repo: https://github.com/kikidesignnet/hotelreviews. I will edit the layout of `welcome.blade.php` and other pages. However, right now I need to get the review form to display once you are logged in.

I checked and compared each file from the tutorial to mine and I couldn't find any difference, the only difference is that I renamed "Tasks" to "Reviews". Can someone look at my code and help me?

Also, when I logged in, I got this error in console.log. I don't understand what the errors are talking about.

```
app.js:69008 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at new App (app.js:69008)
    at constructClassInstance (app.js:51435)
    at updateClassComponent (app.js:55644)
    at beginWork$1 (app.js:57417)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (app.js:37567)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (app.js:37616)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (app.js:37671)
    at beginWork$$1 (app.js:63011)
    at performUnitOfWork (app.js:61926)
    at workLoopSync (app.js:61902)
App @ app.js:69008
constructClassInstance @ app.js:51435
updateClassComponent @ app.js:55644
beginWork$1 @ app.js:57417
callCallback @ app.js:37567
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ app.js:37616
invokeGuardedCallback @ app.js:37671
beginWork$$1 @ app.js:63011
performUnitOfWork @ app.js:61926
workLoopSync @ app.js:61902
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ app.js:61501
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ app.js:60929
updateContainer @ app.js:64334
(anonymous) @ app.js:64759
unbatchedUpdates @ app.js:61664
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ app.js:64758
render @ app.js:64839
./resources/js/index.js @ app.js:69117
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:68898
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
0 @ app.js:69140
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:84
(anonymous) @ app.js:87
app.js:59074 The above error occurred in the <App> component:
    in App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
logCapturedError @ app.js:59074
logError @ app.js:59111
update.callback @ app.js:60463
callCallback @ app.js:51060
commitUpdateEffects @ app.js:51098
commitUpdateQueue @ app.js:51088
commitLifeCycles @ app.js:59391
commitLayoutEffects @ app.js:62575
callCallback @ app.js:37567
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ app.js:37616
invokeGuardedCallback @ app.js:37671
commitRootImpl @ app.js:62313
unstable_runWithPriority @ app.js:68564
runWithPriority$2 @ app.js:49380
commitRoot @ app.js:62153
finishSyncRender @ app.js:61560
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ app.js:61538
scheduleUpdateOnFiber @ app.js:60929
updateContainer @ app.js:64334
(anonymous) @ app.js:64759
unbatchedUpdates @ app.js:61664
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ app.js:64758
render @ app.js:64839
./resources/js/index.js @ app.js:69117
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
./resources/js/app.js @ app.js:68898
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
0 @ app.js:69140
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:20
(anonymous) @ app.js:84
(anonymous) @ app.js:87
app.js:69008 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at new App (app.js:69008)
    at constructClassInstance (app.js:51435)
    at updateClassComponent (app.js:55644)
    at beginWork$1 (app.js:57417)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (app.js:37567)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (app.js:37616)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (app.js:37671)
    at beginWork$$1 (app.js:63011)
    at performUnitOfWork (app.js:61926)
    at workLoopSync (app.js:61902)
```

All I could deduce is that there's something wrong with the binding in App.js, but I checked the binding and all looks fine..... but maybe I'm looking in wrong places.

Comment: My execution is normal, do you run `npm run watch` ?

Comment: I checked the website (http://immense-beach-76879.herokuapp.com/) after I git push to heroku and the form didn't show up once I logged in.

Comment: Okay I ran `npm run watch` and it did show up in localhost. I just don't get why it's not working online...

Comment: You need to run `npm run prod` before deployment and deploy the generated files (app.js & app.css).